# How drupal.org found a website installed module

Tags: 7

I want to know how drupal.org counts the websites which use a specified module, as example in [views module page](https://drupal.org/project/views) reports:

`Reported installs: 717,794 sites currently report using this module. View usage statistics.
Downloads: 4,815,869`.

It is not hard to find the number of downloads but I want to know how drupal.org gets `Reported installs`?

Is there any way to find out the number of websites that use my custom modules that are not published in the drupal.org website?

Answer (score 10):

Drupal.org gets 'reported installs' from the Update manager module. So to do something like that you would need you custom module to report back to a server of yours, and preferrably have your users be notified for that.

Answer (score 8):

I'd guess they track that data when sites request update info (it's the only possible time, thinking about it).

So unless you're explicitly tracking and saving that data yourself somehow, be it through your own module server or other method, then unfortunately not.

Comment: thanks, I guess too, this mean if the site turn off update ,the instanlled module not reported

Comment: @zhilevan FWIW https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/update clive it works like your guessing - unique key and a list of versions of the software your site is runnning are sent to Drupal.org

Answer (score 3):

> **Only sites running the Update Status module report data back to
>   drupal.org.**

As the statistics page for the module mentions

> These statistics are incomplete; only Drupal websites using the **Update
>   Status** module are included in the data.

If you want further details please read https://drupal.org/node/329620

If you want to track your module installs you will need to know how drupal.org generates these statistics. Your first check point should be taking a look at the code in the [Project module](https://drupal.org/project/project).